# Can Cantor's diagonal argument prove $|\mathbb{R}| < \left|2^\mathbb{R}\right|$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, real-numbers

You can prove that $2^\mathbb{N}$ is uncountable using a diagonal argument:

1. Represent each set of numbers as an infinite sequence of binary digits: $\{0, 1, 3, 5\} = 110101000...$
2. If $2^\mathbb{N}$ was countable, then we could enumerate the elements as $S_0$, $S_1$, etc.
3. Make the table with these elements and do the cool diagonal trick to construct an element not in the enumeration.
4. $2^\mathbb{N}$ is uncountable.

It's a really elegant proof, but it doesn't seem like it would work for proving $|\mathbb{R}| < \left|2^{\Bbb R}\right|$. First of all, you can't represent $2^\mathbb{R}$ as an infinite binary string, since the digits in a string are countable. Second, we can't "enumerate" the elements of $2^\mathbb{R}$, as we already know that $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable.

Here's my attempt to adapt the proof:

1. If $|\mathbb{R}| \geq \left|2^R\right|$, then there must exist a *surjective* $f: \mathbb{R} \to 2^\mathbb{R}$.
2. Define $W \in 2^\mathbb{R}$ as $\left\{x \in R: x \notin f(x)\right\}$.
3. Then $\forall x$, either

   1. $x \in f(x), x \notin W, W \neq f(x)$
   2. $x \notin f(x), x \in W, W \neq f(x)$
4. So $\forall x$, $f(x) \neq W$.
5. So $f$ is not surjective, meaning $|\mathbb{R}| < \left|2^R\right|$.

My questions are 1) is this proof valid and 2) is this still a "diagonal argument" or does it have a different name?

Comment: that's good!   $  $ $  $

Comment: That's precisely what is called Cantor's diagonal argument and it proves that for **any** set $X$ (not only $\Bbb N$ or $\Bbb R$) we have $|X| < |2^X|$

Comment: I'll use $P(X)$ for the parts of $X$ and $2^X$ for the functions $X\to \{0,1\}$ because it seems relevant for you. Indeed usually we take a surjective function $f:X\to P(X)$ and then prove that $f(y)=\{x\in X\,:\, x\notin f(x)\}\Rightarrow (y\in f(y)\Leftrightarrow y\notin f(y))$. You can say the same thing with $2^X$: consider a surjection $f:X\to 2^X$ and the function $g(x)=1-f(x)(x)$. Then if $f(y)=g$, we have $f(y)(y)=g(y)(y)=1-f(y)(y)$, impossible. If you look at what it all means in terms of indicator functions, indeed $g^{-1}(1)=\{x\in X\,:\, x\notin (f(x))^{-1}(1)\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the same basic idea as in the diagonal argument to prove that for an arbitrary set $X$, that the power set, $\mathscr P(X)$ has greater cardinality than $X$.

Thus if you define $\beth_0=|\Bbb N|$, and $\beth_n=2^{\beth_{n-1}}$, you get an infinite sequence of levels of infinity.

The idea is to show that there is no surjection from $X$ to $\mathscr P(X)$.  The Russell like set $\{x:x\not\in f(x)\}$ can't be in the image of any proposed surjection $f$.

Comment: Yes I was told.  Still haven't made the transition.  Thanks @SassatelliGiulio